# AngularJS navigation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am trying to implement a navigation into a webpage using angularJS. The problem is that the route does not work at all. The browser console does not give any errors and the ng-view just does not show the templatesUrls.

route.js

```
   var routeApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

routeApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/task.html',
            controller: 'TraineesController'
        })
        .when('/technology', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/technology.html',
            controller: 'TraineesController'
        })
.otherwise({redirectTo:"/technology"});

});
```

Index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/taskman.css"/>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#/technology" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger nav-button-margin">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>&nbsp;Account panel
</a>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div><!-- Closing col-sm-12-->
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('TraineesController', function($scope, $http, $log) {
  getTrainee(); // Load all available tasks

  function getTrainee(){  
  $http.post("ajax/getTrainee.php").success(function(data){
        $scope.trainees = data;
       });
  };
});
```

task.html

```
<div class="widget-box" id="recent-box" ng-controller="TraineesController">
Random text tables
</div>
```

Comment: Don't place the same controller on the body and the route.

Comment: Remove ng-controller tag from body, its already in route.js

Comment: Updated the question still have the same problem. <div ng-include src="'partials/task.html'"></div> seems to work fine, but not the ng-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made two different plunkers, the first one is a plain app just to do an example of routes magic with angular...

[First example, basic routes](http://plnkr.co/edit/uovhmZwUL2U9m3rKHkfL?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.technology = 'this is the tech page';
  $scope.task = 'this is the task';

});

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/technology', {
        templateUrl: 'technology.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/task', {
        templateUrl: 'task.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/technology'
      });

  }
]);
```

The second example is an myApp example based on your application, it's basicaly your application but slightly different...

[Second example, your app](http://plnkr.co/edit/dYP0wg37nvdyYo0kb5bE?p=info)

```
// I like to keep the app.js file "clean", what means that this file will only
// load the app modules and declare the DI of the app...
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',            // ngRoutes directive from angularjs
  'myAppControllers',   // controllers module, u can add how controllers wtv u need
  'myAppRoutes',        // routes module, you can keep the routes configs separated or in the same file
]);
// start the modules, other way to do this is to put this lines in every 
// single controllers or route file, what is ugly
angular.module('myAppRoutes',[]);
angular.module('myAppControllers',[]);
```

Comment: You sir are my hero. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

remove the `;` from here:

```
.when('/technology', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/technology.html',
        controller: 'TraineesController'
    }) // <-----here you have a ; remove it and it will work.
.otherwise({redirectTo:"/technology"});
```

---

`;` broke the chaining and caused a syntax error there.

---

#### update:

you can remove this controller:

```
<body ng-controller="TraineesController">
```

and instead you can place the controller in the respective templates.

---

#### [checkout this plunkr demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/r72kayt6gCTQyeVDCOZp?p=preview)

Comment: do you have controllers defined? if you got any error in the browser console, share that too.

Comment: my app.js
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('TraineesController', function($scope, $http,$log) {
    getTrainee(); // Load all available tasks
    function getTrainee(){  
    $http.post("ajax/getTrainee.php").success(function(data){
        $scope.trainees = data;
        });
    };
    });

task.html
    <div class="widget-box" id="recent-box" ng-    controller="TraineesController">
...Other functions...

I removed the controller from body but it still does not work

Comment: checkout the demo i have provided in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the demo the navigation started to work, but it keeps popping up with an error - Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TraineesController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: yes that happens when we use the directive but we do not have that controller written there.

Comment: Your example perfectly works, but I am trying to implement it to my system, that is why I am getting the error and trying to figure it out. Thank you for all the support, hopefully this error will be handled. :)

Comment: See angular does not find the `ng-controller="TraineesController"`, that is why this error is coming up, try declaring this and see if this helps.

Comment: I have declared it in the app.js (See the question in the top), do I need to point it out anywhere? Thanks for the help.